# How to implement MTI in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

For example I have a User model and a table that has fields: Name, Email and Password. There is also a model of Employer that inherits all the User model and should have its own unique fields, such as for example: Company, Phone etc..

How can I realize a Multiple table inheritance?

Comment: In addition to the question: at the moment I am creating a system of user authentication/authorization in the application for freelancers. I set up Devise and created a User model from which wanted to inherit the future of the field for Employers and Employees. The user may be employers and employees at the same time as it works on upwork.com. MTI seems to me a good solution for this problem, but maybe you know a better solution.

Comment: Maybe you could extract common user functionality to `ActsAsUser` concern and include it to both Employer and Employee models (which are in other aspects completely separate)?

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MTI is poorly supported by Rails. There is a gem [active_record-acts_as](https://github.com/krautcomputing/active_record-acts_as) which does the thing.

UPDATE:

I decided to extend my answer after reading your comment about employers/employees. At the moment I'm working on an app where there are also different types of users and instead of storing only `:current_user_id` in session I've decided to store `current_profile_type` and `current_profile_id`, so `current_profile` could be an instance of different models.

There might be similar functionality for those models; it could be extracted into concern. Different views could be rendered depending on certain class of `current_profile`.

Maybe this approach could be applied in your situation, too.

Comment: The gem development moved: https://github.com/krautcomputing/active_record-acts_as